# Change Screen Resolution

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I've got a problem. I need to change screen resolution inside of my QT Project(like in some games for example). I have heard that I need to use Windows API, like following:

```
DEVMODE devmode;
devmode.dmPelsWidth = 1024;
devmode.dmPelsHeight = 768;
devmode.dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;
devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);

long result = ChangeDisplaySettings(&devmode, 0);
qDebug() << "RESULT OF CHANGE DISPLAY :"<< result;
```

But Qt says: "'DEVMODE': undeclared identifier". How can I fix it? Maybe I need to include some libraries?

Comment: Did you include wingdi.h?

Comment: Pavel, sorry for not answering so long, I had some work. I tried include "WinGDI.h", but now it found 560 errors in wingdi.h.
All of them are:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\WinGDI.h:285: error: C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ptPosition'//or other
and then 2 errors like
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\WinGDI.h:285: ошибка: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
And after the error like that

Answer (score 0):

You have to include windows.h header. Here is an working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

int main() {

    DEVMODE devmode;
    devmode.dmPelsWidth = 1024;
    devmode.dmPelsHeight = 768;
    devmode.dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;
    devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);

    long result = ChangeDisplaySettings(&devmode, 0);

    return 0;
}
```